# Retrofit don't get data with query but the url works in the browser

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to get some user from randomuser.me public API, but I can't get that retrofit work when I try to put a query in the url.

This is the request that I'm trying to do and if you put it in the browser, you can see that seems correct, because works, but in retrofit method I don't have any value.

https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20

**CODE:**

```
mCall = ApplicationConfig.getApiService().getRandomUsers(20);
        Log.e(TAG, mCall.request().url().toString());
        mCall.enqueue(new Callback<RandomUserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RandomUserResponse> call, Response<RandomUserResponse> response) {

                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    in.onRandomUserData(response.body().getResults());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RandomUserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }

public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("api/")
    Call<RandomUserResponse> getRandomUsers(@Query("results") Integer results);
}

public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://randomuser.me/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

If I try to do this.... the retrofit method works:

```
@GET("api/")
Call<RandomUserResponse> getRandomUsers();

mCall = ApplicationConfig.getApiService().getRandomUsers();
```

...
...

My question is, ¿Why I can't get the users adding the query if I put it in the browser and it works?

Comment: Try removing the backslash from the API call `@GET("api")`

Comment: I just found the error: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "U9 4QT"

Comment: In your pojo class you have declared a variable as double which is actually not a double value, if you post your pojo class here it would be helpfull

Comment: Yep, I know. I think that is only some data that return the api. I'll fix it